# The type initializer for 'Stripe.Infrastructure.StripeTypeRegistry' threw an exception?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

GV there is my class. The code looks fine, no errors when running but after I Create Customer Object and Register it on Stripe the problem will appear. The example code I try to call  is this :
Stripe.Customer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

Before I put the following code to my program it worked fine. Now it keeps throwing errors:

```
   //Create Customer Object and Register it on Stripe  
    Stripe.CustomerCreateOptions myCustomer = new 
    Stripe.CustomerCreateOptions();
    myCustomer.Email = tParams.Buyer_Email;
    myCustomer.SourceToken = newToken.Id;
    var customerService = new Stripe.CustomerService();
    Stripe.Customer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);
```

And The code which I am using from URL 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/implement-stripe-payment-gateway-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You need to debug and dig down into inner exceptions to find out *what* exception the type initializer actually threw. We can't tell anything from this code.

Comment: here is the inner exception "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"